# Multiline string in Javascript function call (Firefox user.js)

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

I have a user.js file which sets `user_prefs()` for the new tab page in firefox. When I have the function call on a single line with escaped quotes, it works fine, but when the parameter is a multi-line string it doesn't work. Any ideas how I can have this work as a multiline string (for readability)?

Works:

```js
user_pref("browser.newtabpage.pinned", "[{\"url\":\"https://amazon.com/\",\"label\":\"amazon\",\"baseDomain\":\"amazon.com\"},{\"url\":\"https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox\",\"label\":\"mail\"},{\"url\":\"https://www.facebook.com/\",\"label\":\"facebook\",\"baseDomain\":\"facebook.com\"},{\"url\":\"https://twitter.com/\",\"label\":\"twitter\",\"baseDomain\":\"twitter.com\"},{\"url\":\"https://www.instagram.com/\",\"label\":\"instagram\",\"baseDomain\":\"instagram.com\"},{\"url\":\"https://www.reddit.com/\",\"label\":\"reddit\",\"baseDomain\":\"reddit.com\"},{\"url\":\"https://www.youtube.com/\",\"label\":\"youtube\",\"baseDomain\":\"youtube.com\"},{\"url\":\"https://keep.google.com/\",\"label\":\"keep.google\",\"baseDomain\":\"keep.google.com\"},{\"url\":\"https://app.plex.tv/desktop/#!/\",\"label\":\"app.plex\",\"baseDomain\":\"app.plex.tv\"},{\"url\":\"https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=home\",\"baseDomain\":\"phoronix.com\"},{\"url\":\"http://192.168.50.2\",\"label\":\"nas\",\"baseDomain\":\"192.168.50.2\"},{\"url\":\"http://192.168.50.2:8080\",\"label\":\"app\",\"baseDomain\":\"192.168.50.2\"},{\"url\":\"https://www.protondb.com/\",\"label\":\"proton\",\"baseDomain\":\"protondb.com\"}]");
```

Doesn't work:

```js
user_pref("browser.newtabpage.pinned",
`[
    {
        "url": "https://amazon.com/",
        "label": "amazon",
        "baseDomain": "amazon.com"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox",
        "label": "mail"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/",
        "label": "facebook",
        "baseDomain": "facebook.com"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://twitter.com/",
        "label": "twitter",
        "baseDomain": "twitter.com"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.instagram.com/",
        "label": "instagram",
        "baseDomain": "instagram.com"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.reddit.com/",
        "label": "reddit",
        "baseDomain": "reddit.com"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
        "label": "youtube",
        "baseDomain": "youtube.com"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://keep.google.com/",
        "label": "keep.google",
        "baseDomain": "keep.google.com"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://app.plex.tv/desktop/#!/",
        "label": "app.plex",
        "baseDomain": "app.plex.tv"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=home",
        "baseDomain": "phoronix.com"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://192.168.50.2",
        "label": "nas",
        "baseDomain": "192.168.50.2"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://192.168.50.2:8080",
        "label": "app",
        "baseDomain": "192.168.50.2"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://www.protondb.com/",
        "label": "proton",
        "baseDomain": "protondb.com"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://lichess.org",
        "label": "lichess",
        "baseDomain": "lichess.org"
    },
    {
        "url": "https://app.ynab.com",
        "label": "ynab",
        "baseDomain": "app.ynab.com"
    }
]`);
```

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: Are the line breaks allowed in the value? What happens when you set this value containing line breaks in `about:config`?

Comment: Instead of escaping all the nested quotes, you could use single quotes around the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the user.js uses a limiter parser, so I guess template string just don't work there

Try using basic strings with newline escapes, like

```
user_pref('browser.newtabpage.pinned',
'[                                       \
    {                                    \
        "url": "https://amazon.com/",    \
        "label": "amazon",               \
        "baseDomain": "amazon.com"       \
    },                                   \
    {                                    \
        "url": "https://app.ynab.com",   \
        "label": "ynab",                 \
        "baseDomain": "app.ynab.com"     \
    }                                    \
');
```

(note that I use ' strings to avoid " escapes)

Comment: I think this is headed in the right direction, but unfortunately it seems the parser still isn't happy. The browser console (Menu --> More Tools --> Browser Console) throws an error

`user.js:176: prefs parse error: unexpected escape sequence character after '\'`

Line 176 for me is the 2nd line in the code you provided

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` to convert in to object (or even write is as object) and then `JSON.stringify` to convert it back to exactly the string it expects

```
user_pref(
   "browser.newtabpage.pinned",
   JSON.stringify(
       { blah: 999 }
   )
)
```

Comment: This is indeed the best way to write it, but doesn't explain why their code didn't work.

Comment: If the JSON-re-stringified one works then I'll cal this magic (actually a bug)

Comment: It's strange that the application requires the argument to be JSON in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work, I believe the firefox prefs parser is blocking keywords/functions. I can't use JSON.stringify or other functions, I can't even set variables. Looks like there may not be a way to do this in user.js